# Multiprocessing a for loop?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have an array (called `data_inputs`) containing the names of hundreds of astronomy images files. These images are then manipulated. My code works and takes a few seconds to process each image. However, it can only do one image at a time because I'm running the array through a `for` loop:

```
for name in data_inputs:
    sci=fits.open(name+'.fits')
    #image is manipulated
```

There is no reason why I have to modify an image before any other, so is it possible to utilise all 4 cores on my machine with each core running through the for loop on a different image?

I've read about the `multiprocessing` module but I'm unsure how to implement it in my case.
I'm keen to get `multiprocessing` to work because eventually I'll have to run this on 10,000+ images.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You can simply use [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def process_image(name):
    sci=fits.open('{}.fits'.format(name))
    <process>

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()                         # Create a multiprocessing Pool
    pool.map(process_image, data_inputs)  # process data_inputs iterable with pool
```

Comment: It might be better to use:
`pool = Pool(os.cpu_count())`

This is a more generic way of using multiprocessing.

Comment: Note: `os.cpu_count()` was added in Python 3.4.  For Python 2.x, use `multiprocessing.cpu_count()`.

Comment: `Pool()` is the same as `Pool(os.cpu_count())`

Comment: To elaborate on @Tim's comment - `Pool()` called without a value for `processes` is the same as `Pool(processes=cpu_count())` regardless of whether you are using Python 3 or 2 - so the best practice in EITHER version is to use `Pool()`. https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: @Alko :  I am unable to understand what is "data_inputs" here. You haven't defined it. What value should I give it?

Comment: @LiorMagen , if I'm not mistaken, using Pool(os.cpu_count()) will make the OS freeze until the processing is over, as you don't leave the OS any free cores. For a lot of users Pool(os.cpu_count() - 1) might be a better choice

Comment: @shayelk You are absolutely right and I always leave at least one CPU alone. I gave it just as an example for using multiprocessing.

Comment: There must be pool.close() at the end.

Comment: @Abhishekdotpy It is the same name iterable used by the OP. The OP was looping `for name in data_inputs:`

Comment: @shayelk You are indeed mistaken. Every version of Windows since 3.1, every Apple OS since A/UX, and every version of Linux ever has supported **pre-emptive multitasking**, which means that even a task which consumes all cores can still be "interrupted" by the OS to handle things like window drawing and cursor input, so running a CPU-bound workload at ((n − 1)/n)% capacity to avoid OS freezing won't help you. (The only times I've seen modern OSes freeze up due to resource use were from a kernel that wrongly assumed an SSD going swap thrashing, but your suggestion won't help that, either!)

Comment: Not to mention that Python doesn't even set core affinity, so it could be that sometimes the OS puts more than 1 Python process onto the same core anyway, when it feels like it...

Answer (score 35):

You can use `multiprocessing.Pool`:

```python
from multiprocessing import Pool
class Engine(object):
    def __init__(self, parameters):
        self.parameters = parameters
    def __call__(self, filename):
        sci = fits.open(filename + '.fits')
        manipulated = manipulate_image(sci, self.parameters)
        return manipulated

try:
    pool = Pool(8) # on 8 processors
    engine = Engine(my_parameters)
    data_outputs = pool.map(engine, data_inputs)
finally: # To make sure processes are closed in the end, even if errors happen
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: I am unable to understand what is "data_inputs" here. You haven't defined it. What value should I give it?

Comment: It actually stems from alko's answer, I'm citing his comment (see the code block): "proces data_inputs iterable with pool". So `data_inputs` is an iterable (like in a standard `map`).

Comment: The [python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) only shows that one can pass a function to `pool.map(func, iterable[, chunksize])`. When passing an object, will this object be shared by all the processes? Thus, could I have all processes write to the same list `self.list_` in the object?

Answer (score 10):

Alternatively

```
with Pool() as pool: 
    pool.map(fits.open, [name + '.fits' for name in datainput])
```

Comment: `TypeError: 'Pool' object is not callable`

Comment: Sorry my mistake it is "pool.map" not just "pool". I fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to use `imap_unordered` with `chunksize` if you are only using a `for` loop to iterate over an iterable. It will return results from each loop as soon as they are calculated. `map` waits for all results to be computed and hence is blocking.

Comment: Would you please provide an example of what you mean?