# multithreading in python for loop

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have a for loop where I am passing list of schema names to the loop. I want to execute these in parallel because there is no relation between these schemas.

I am using Python 2.6.

Creating dictionary here with schema information.

```
region_by_schema = {}
region_by_schema['UTEST_TT'] = 'tt'
region_by_schema['UTEST_V3'] = 'v3'
region_by_schema['UTEST_WRITE_SERVER'] = ''
region_by_schema['UTEST_PROPERTY'] = ''
region_by_schema['UTEST_PROJECT'] = ''
```

Looping through schema here:

```
for base_schema in region_by_schema.keys():
    do_one_user(base_schema, opt_password)
```

In `do_one_user` I am creating a directory with `base_schema` name and I am doing some work there.

So I want to execute these 5 schemas in parallel so that my work will finish fast. I want to put the code below in threads or multiprocessing:

```
for base_schema in region_by_schema.keys():
    do_one_user(base_schema, opt_password)
```

Please let me know the approach.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Multiprocessing a for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20190668/python-multiprocessing-a-for-loop)

Comment: Use multiprocessing: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: It might be worth checking out iPython/iPython notebooks. They can be quite useful for [parallel computing](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/parallel/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you read instruction of threading and learn how to use it. Here is [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html).

```
from threading import Thread

yourSchemas = [schema1, schema2, schema3]
t = []
def test(region_by_schema):
    for base_schema in region_by_schema.keys():
        do_one_user(base_schema, opt_password)

    for schema in yourSchemas:
        t.append(Thread(target=test, args=[schema]))

    for i in range(len(yourSchemas)):
        t.start()
        t.join()
```

Comment: I tried this but it is still not executing parallel.

Comment: @user3743797  Could you please update your question by posting your latest code?

Comment: from threading import Thread

yourSchemas = [schema1, schema2, schema3]
t = []
def test(region_by_schema):
    for base_schema in region_by_schema.keys():
        do_one_user(base_schema, opt_password)

    for schema in yourSchemas:
        myThread = Thread(target=test, args=[schema])
 myThread.start()
 t.append(myThread)

    for i in range(len(yourSchemas)):        
        t[i].join()

This will work but now i am facing different issue, currently looking into this.

Thanks for your help

Comment: @user3743797 If it works, please confirm it as an answer, thanks!

Comment: This is working but now i am facing another problem.

Comment: This is working but now i am facing another problem.
Using some logic i created 5 directories and those directories are having subdirectories with some data.

UTEST_TT,
UTEST_V3,
UTEST_WRITE_SERVER,
UTEST_PROPERTY,
UTEST_PROJECT,

So now i want multithreading on these directories.In one thread i am changing the directory using os.chdir(./UTEST_TT/init) and in another thread i am changing it another directory.
Because of this my process is failing.

So is there a way i can change excecution of the process to current directory instead of changing the os path.

Comment: @user3743797 I didn't get your point.I suggest you open another question and post code you have tried so that we could see your problem clearly. It's way of working in Stackoverflow.