# How to execute a multithreaded selenium program in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I'd like to execute the following code using a multithreaded solution

Can anyone suggest how to improve the solution?

```
from selenium import webdriver

with open('proxy.txt', 'r') as f: 
    for line in f:
        print ("Connected with IP: {}".format(line))
        PROXY = line # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://%s' % PROXY)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
        driver.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com")
        driver.quit()
```

Comment: Please explain more detailed and more deeply what you are trying to archive.

Comment: @AK47 i try it but i cant achieve my goal.

Comment: @KlausD. i use this code for visits but i need to make him doing this process on multi threads so it can work faster? i hope im clear

Comment: @markcontira see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import os 
from multiprocessing import Pool

from selenium import webdriver

def check_ip(proxy):
    print ("Connected with IP: {}".format(proxy))
    options = webdriver.chrome.options.Options()
    options.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://{}'.format(proxy))
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com")
    driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('./proxy.txt') as f:
        proxies = f.read().splitlines()
    with Pool() as pool:
        pool.map(check_ip, proxies)
```

Solution is based on the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20190668/multiprocessing-a-for-loop)