# Multiprocessing For Loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a few CPUs at my disposal on a virtual machine. I have a rather simple for loop to compute, which I would like to multiprocess as it computes separate parts.

```
results = []
for i in range(n_iterations):
   result = compute_value(i)
   results.append(result)
```

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20190668/multiprocessing-a-for-loop) consider the case where there is an data_inputs list that you want to iterate through. I tried to adapt it to my case, but it failed and I am just utterly confused. Any help to adapt their solution to my slightly different case would be appreciated.

EDIT: To clarify why I am confused, this is my code:

```
def compute_value(i):
    return i
results = []
def a_function(i):
    results.append(compute_value(i))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()
    pool.map(a_function, range(10))
```

But when I print(results), I just get the output [] [] [].

Comment: Just use the range? I don't understand the problem exactly

Answer (score 2):

Why not use something like this?

```
pool = Pool()
results = pool.map(compute_value, range(n_iterations))
print(results)
```