# Multiprocessing in nested loops?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a nested loop with a huge range of data. In some point it takes hours to calculated the values. I was wondering if somehow I can speed it up by using multiproccessing package of python. Here is my code:

```
def update_selections(all_selection):
    selections_filtered_all = []
    selections_filtered_all_minus_1 = []
    for n, values in enumerate(all_selection):
         items_set = set()
         sum_length = 0
         for y in values:
             items_set.update(y)
             sum_length += 1
         if len(sum_length) == 300000000:
              selections_filtered_all.append(1)

    selections_filtered_all_minus_1.exted(selections_filtered_all)
```

By following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20192251/2426420) answer, this is my way, however it's not working:

```
def update_selections(all_selection):
    selections_filtered_all = []
    selections_filtered_all_minus_1 = []
    pool = Pool() 
    for n, x in enumerate(all_selection):
        pool.map(process_selections, x)
    
    selections_filtered_all_minus_1.exted(selections_filtered_all)


def process_selections(values):
    items_set = set()
    sum_length = 0
    for y in values:
        items_set.update(y)
        sum_length += 1
    if len(sum_length) == 300000000:
        selections_filtered_all.append(1)


    return essences_set, sum_length, selections_filtered_all

all_selection = ['xfRxx', 'asdeEFD', ...]
update_selections(all_selection)
```

I don't understand how to bring pool() in a loop. Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: what do you think `pool.map(process_selections, x)` does? it creates a process for each value present in `x` and passes such value to the function specified (i.e. `process_selections`). So that function should process *one* value only. Note it may or may not make sense in your case to spawn a process to elaborate one simple value at a time. Maybe break things down in chunks differently from the original source `all_selection`

Comment: I suppose it is another loop and iteration which passes each element of x to process_selections. Maybe I need to replace x with all_selection and get rid of first loop?

Comment: in `process_selections` try printing its argument `values`. You will see it is *one* value only

Comment: Also, let each process return a value to `Pool.map` (or more than one value) so that the main process can append it to the `selections_filtered_all` list. You cannot expect each process to do it. There are other ways of course (see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues)), but they're unnecessary

Comment: I am not sure if i'm understanding correctly. Because even with your changes all the program blocked

Answer (score 0):

Try this (but see my notes following):

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool


def process_selection(values):
    items_set = set()
    sum_length = 0
    for y in values:
        items_set.update(y)
        sum_length += 1
    return 1 if len(sum_length) == 300000000 else None
    
def update_selections(all_selection):
    selections_filtered_all_minus_1 = []
    pool = Pool()
    # Just keep the 1 values:
    selections_filtered_all = list(filter(lambda x: x == 1, pool.map(process_selection, all_section)))
    # You mean extend, right?
    selections_filtered_all_minus_1.extend(selections_filtered_all)
```

**Notes**

There is something a little odd about function `process_selection` (and your original logic). It creates a set that is never used to any purpose. In essence you are just counting the number of elements in variable `values` and you can save a lot of time by not creating the set and adding elements to it. In fact, if `values` implements the `len` method, you do not even need a loop.

If, however, the intention was to get a count of the number of elements in `values` *after removing duplicates*, then you should be taking the length of the set:

```py
def process_selection(values):
    items_set = set(values)
    return 1 if len(items_set) == 300000000 else None
```

This makes the function far less CPU intensive than before and it becomes less clear to what extent multiprocessing will improve performance. The problem is that *it appears* that you are passing very large data items across address spaces, which in itself carries large overhead.

I am also assuming that the number of elements in the `all_selection` *iterable* is not very large even if each of these elements may be quite large. If this assumption is erroneous, you might wish to look into using the `imap` method instead of the `map` methods with a suitable *chunksize* argument. Doing so will prevent the creation of a large list result which is only going to be filtered into another list (`imap` instead returns an *iterable* that when iterated gives each result one by one and would be more memory efficient and perfectly suitable as input to `filter`).